# Noticed silicone seam in shower was peeling and had lots of mold behind it

Tags: shower, mold, silicone

My shower has plastic sides that are sealed together with a silicone seam along the edges. Today while cleaning it I noticed it was starting to peel. I pulled it back a little and a bunch of moldy water came out. I started stripping the rest out to replace it and I'm a bit freaked out. Does the tub base have a pan that catches any residual water down at the edge or is this water exposed to drywall that could be rotting behind it?

[image]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As an anecdote, when we redid our tub surround 30 years ago, we had an acrylic/PVC/something surround over plaster & lath walls. There was caulk on the seams and it was peeling off. We removed the surround and, much to my shock, discovered that the plaster was in fantastically good condition behind it. We did pull the plaster off the lath and replaced it with cement board before tiling, but this situation does not automatically mean that your drywall is soggy.

Answer (score 3):

Typically there's a flange back there with the shower wall shingling on top to prevent water intrusion. Just strip the old sealant, clean everything, dry everything out, and apply fresh sealant. Silicone is a safe choice. Otherwise get a sealant that specifically mentions tubs and showers. It should mention "class 25" or higher on the tube.